# Dynamic parallel execution of a function for items in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, promise

`Promise.map` executes a `function x()` concurrently for items in an array. Consider the scenario the array is getting populated and growing dynamically.Can the `function x()` be executed for each item added into the array dynamically?

For example: 
**1)** 
`time : 11:00 AM` 
`arrayX : [a,b]` 
`-> function x() execution is started for a & b` 
**2)** 
`time : 11:10 AM` 
`arrayX : [a,b,c] (now c is added to arrayX)` 
`function x() execution is in-progress for a & b and started for c`

Comment: You can use async module which have several way to do it.

Comment: so, the function could take more than 10 minutes to complete?

Comment: to answer the question, how is it that `c` is added to the array after 10 minutes? push?

Comment: @jaromanda-x :  `c` is nothing but an socket message. Messages are getting published by zeromq and those messages are populated into array and then `function x()` is getting executed for each element in the array. The time `10 minutes` is just an example.

Comment: great information about something nobody asked ... so how is c being added to the array, push? or, is `[a,b]` one "message" then `[a,b,c]` is a different message where a and b are identical to the original a and b?

Comment: Both [a,b] and [a,b,c] denote the same array, where c is added to existing array

Comment: by what method, is it push? because it could be splice or array[arr.length] = c or concat ... I was trying to help, but I'm losing all interest now